# Pandas background gradient styling per column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am on `Python 3.10.13` and `pandas version: '2.1.4'`. I was looking at the [Table Visualisation user guide for pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html). They give an example for adding background gradient to numeric columns. Below is a minimally reproducible version of their example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def make_pretty(styler):
    styler.set_caption("Weather Conditions")
    styler.format_index(lambda v: v.strftime("%A"))
    styler.background_gradient(axis=None, vmin=1, vmax=5, cmap="YlGnBu")
    return styler


weather_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*5,
                          index=pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01", periods=10),
                          columns=["Tokyo", "Beijing"])

weather_df.loc["2021-01-04":"2021-01-08"].style.pipe(make_pretty)
```

The above applies the `vmin` and `vmax` across all the numeric cells in the data frame. How can I add background gradients per column such that `vmin` and `vmax` correspond to each column's specific values and so the gradients are distinct by column?

I have tried the below to see whether it would pick up min and max automatically if applied across columns, but it does not work:

```
styler.background_gradient(axis='columns, cmap="YlGnBu")
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' Styler.background_gradient function is used to apply a color gradient to each cell of the data frame. In the code you entered, with the axis=None parameter, the gradient is applied to the entire DataFrame (both along rows and columns) and the vmin and vmax values are fixed for the entire DataFrame. If you want to apply a gradient to each column separately according to its min and max values, you can use axis=0 (or 'index').

```
    def make_pretty(styler):
       styler.set_caption("Weather Conditions")
       styler.format_index(lambda v: v.strftime("%A"))
       styler.background_gradient(axis=0, cmap="YlGnBu") 
       return styler

    weather_df.loc["2021-01-04":"2021-01-08"].style.pipe(make_pretty)
```